# Why is spring’s DI/IoC considered more decoupled than just regulars OO?

Tags: spring, oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I’m trying to learn spring coming from a regular OO background.

In regular OO if you wanted to decouple a dependency. You would do it by

```
Car car = CarFactory.getCar();
```

where you can have BigCar and SmallCar implements Car.

In spring, the dependency is decoupled by

```
@Autowire
BigCar car;
```

Or configured via XML.

Question is how is that **more decoupled**? In all 3 cases, you either

1. Change 1 line of code in your factory
2. Change 1 line of code below @Autowire
3. Change 1 line of XML code

Comment: You would `@Autowire` a `Car` not a specific type. Yes you can change one line in your factory but it isn't dependency injection. The class itself needs to now where to obtain the dependency from (your factory) which couples it to the factory and the logic within. Decoupled means it uses a `Car` and how it is obtained isn't important.

Comment: How would @Autowire Car work? It wouldn't if you have two sub types, Spring won't know which to instantiate.

Comment: You would create a single instance, that is also what your ` CarFactory.getCar();` is doing. Else you can always use qualifiers to obtain a specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is more decoupled because the object which wants a reference to a Car (in this example) does not need to contain any code that retrieves or creates a Car. In the case of dependency injection, the dependency injection container creates the beans, establishes the relationships and satisfies dependencies between beans.
The bean creation is completely decoupled from the code that uses the beans; it can be defined in the form of Java configuration or XML in the case of Spring.
An additional advantage is that dependency injection establishes a single mechanism to establish relationships and satisfy dependencies between beans.

Answer (score 0):

In spring there's a concept called Inversion of Control(IoC).
  Basically it means,

> *Inversion of Control is a principle in software engineering by which the control of objects or portions of a program is transferred to a container or framework.*

You can check it here https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring

So using spring we're not creating objects where we needed but we're delegating this responsibility to the spring by just notifying where it should be created. In the above example by using **@Autowired**. Which is obviously loose coupled than in OO design.